# I need to obtain distance and speed vs time in one direction gravitational force

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I got frustrated from trying to solve supposing simple physic's problem. All book, textbooks, lectures are always calculation escape velocity from conservation of energy law. I am more ambitious more than that, I want to calculate r(t) and v(t) in one dimension if a stone is thrown up with high speed and observe myself, as a function of time, what is r(t) and r'(t) as a function in starting velocity on a massive planet.
The equation is simple but all trials failed
m*r''=G*m*M/r^2 =→
I wrote a code but it gave me the distance embedded in an equation which it cannot solve (Mathematica12.1)

The trial:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Delete All Output;
DSolve[r''[t]*(r[t])^2 + (G*M) == 0, r[t], t]
```

And this was the solution!

```
Solve[(-((2 G M ArcTanh[Sqrt[C[1] + (2 G M)/r[t]]/Sqrt[C[1]]])/C[1]^(
     3/2)) + (Sqrt[C[1] + (2 G M)/r[t]] r[t])/C[1])^2 == (t + C[2])^2,
  r[t]]
```

And Mathematica 12.1 can't solve its solution

Also used NDSolve:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Delete All Output;
Clear[k, R, v];
R = 6371 E 3;
k = 5.972 E 27;
v = 500;
NDSolve[{k + y[x]^2 (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, y[0] == R, 
  y'[0] == v}, y, {x, 0, 100}]


Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I got This comment:
{s} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Any help to get r(t), and v(t) for one dimensional motion described by universal gravity law?

Comment: Do you mean to have `s = NDSolve[...`? If so, you’ve missed this in what you show here. If not, what you have written will not work, because you are missing `s = NDSolve[...`.

Comment: Though not causing problem here, the `Delete All Output;` is meaningless…

Comment: You are not far, but you need to be more careful. You wrote "...as a function in starting velocity on a massive planet", but you do not provide the initial velocity as an input for DSolve. In other words, DSolve generates a solution with 2 unknown parameters `C[1]` and `C[2]`. They contain the dependence on the initial velocity and position. The simplest way is to provide initial conditions to DSolve.

Comment: @yarchik The first thing I tried is with initial condition: 
DSolve[{r''[t]*r[t]^2 + G*M == 0, r[0] == R, r'[0] == vi}, r'[t], t], it just repeated the input in the output!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can divide your equation divide by m. Then you get: r'' == M G / r^2, independent of m.

For an example we choose an earthlike scenario. You may then change the code to your liking. If the planet is massive or not has only an effect on the escape velocity, the overall picture remains the same (as long as we deal with Newtonian physics), The only interesting case is, when the start velocity is around the escape velocity. Is it smaller, the body returns to earth, is it larger, then the body keeps on going. When the start velocity is equal to the escape velocity, it keeps on going but in this case the velocity tends to zero:

```
G = 6.674 10^-11;
r0 = 6.37 10^6;
mass = 6 10^24;
r0 = 6.371 10^6;
vesc = Sqrt[2 G mass/r0];
tmax = 10^5;

Manipulate[
 eq = {r''[t] == -mass G/r[t]^2, r[0] == r0, r'[0] == v0};
 res[t_] = r[t] /. NDSolve[eq, r, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
 GraphicsGrid[{{Plot[res[t], {t, 0, tmax}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Position"]}, {Plot[res'[t], {t, 0, tmax}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Velocity"]}}]
 , {v0, 0.97 vesc, 1.001 vesc}, TrackedSymbols :> {v0}]
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect. I appreciate your help